# How to consume DELETE request from windows client application

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, url-parameters, http-delete

In my web API delete request, which containing multiple parameters.I need to consume this DELETE request using C# windows form application and my code as bellow.

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            person p = new person { ID = 1, SID = 5, Name = "paul"};

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2733/");
            var response = client.DeleteAsync("api/person/").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.Write("Success");
            }
            else
                Console.Write("Error");
        }
    }
```

This is how I consume this using Postman, and its **works fine**`http://localhost:2733/api/person/1/5/"paul"` How to consume this using my windows client. I try these two way,

```
var response = client.DeleteAsync("api/person/",p).Result;
```

and

```
var response = client.DeleteAsync("api/person/"+1+5+"paul").Result;
```

But those are not working. How can I pass parameters to DELETE request.

**Updated:**

This is my controller class,

```
[Route("api/person/{id:int}/{pid:int}/{pname}")]
[HttpDelete]
public void Delete(int id, int pid, string pname)
{
    var pModel = new PModel
    {
        ID = id,
        SID = pid,
        Name= pname
    };
    Person p = new Person();
    p.deletePerson(pModel);
}
```

This is Person class

```
public void deletePerson(PModel p)
{
    try
    {
        string sql = $"DELETE from person WHERE ID = {p.ID} AND SID = {p.SID} AND Name= {p.Name}"; ;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        long x = cmd.LastInsertedId;
    }
    catch (MySqlException x)
    {
        int errr = x.Number;

        Console.WriteLine(errr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're using the word "consume" incorrectly. You'd *issue* a delete request from the client.

Comment: "not working" isn't a great description of what's going wrong.

Comment: blocking on `async` APIs with UI is a recipe for deadlock (`.Result`). async all the way or not at all. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Don't you need a `/` between the 1 and 5?

Comment: @spender agreed, but this won't deadlock as you cannot await a void method.

Comment: Try `var response = client.DeleteAsync($"api/person/{p.ID}/{p.SID}/{p.Name}").Result;`

Comment: @mjwills I dont understand what u ask, when I run the program with `"api/person/"+1+5+"paul"` **Error** print in console

Comment: @Crowcoder I am not clear,can you provide me sample code

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Thank you sir,its works :) you are genius

Comment: Look at Vidmantas' comment. Don't  you see that in postman you have a slash between the 1 and the  5?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes :) Vidmantas'  one works

Comment: @Rooter No problem,glad to hear it worked, I have posted it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below. It should replicate the way you have tried consuming your API through PostMan.

`var response = client.DeleteAsync($"api/person/{p.ID}/{p.SID}/\"{p.Name}\"").Result;`

Comment: Sir this code print **Success**  and no any errors display in application, but records are not delete

Comment: @Rooter I mean, you have not even posted your controller code so as far as we know, it is an empty function that will return `Success` always as long as the route is correct (which it is since you've got the response back). Try and edit your question or create a new question showing your controller code becomes it could be (and most likely will) a completely separate problem not related to your initial question.

Comment: @Rooter No problems, are you getting any exceptions in the Api side then? Can you tell us what the value of sql variable is?

Comment: No any errors in API sir. How can I see the value of sql variable sir?

Comment: Sir I put a break line in this line `string sql = $"DELETE from person WHERE ID = {p.ID} AND SID = {p.SID} AND Name= {p.Name}";`

when i consume API using windows  form, `p.name = "paul"` 
but when I consume it using Postman, `p.name = "\"paul\" "`

Comment: @Rooter Ah ok, so you'ive edited my answer by changing `{p.Name}` to `\"{p.Name}\"` - a bit unusual to have the values like that but what can you do. This should work now for you.

Comment: Thank you sir,now its works fine. Glad to find person like you :)
what was the reason values come like that